# how to debug http triggered azure function with parameters and file

Tags: azure-functions

How can I run a debugger on this Azure Http Triggered Function I created?

Normally my Azure Logic App calls this function which is how I use it but I can't figure out how to debug this.  I have Postman but I don't know how to provide those 2 parameters plus the csv file that the Logic app passes over.

Any thoughts?

if I type this into a local web browser it does get triggered, but I'm stuck on how to transmit the csv file attachment.

http://localhost:7071/api/TradematchHttpFunctions?name=hello&source=user

[image: screenshot]

update*
in postman I've tried 2 different ways to attach file

1. body section, form-data, key: name of file, value: attached file.
   debugger does run but I get error on JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody)

error message:

System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: TradematchHttpFunctions. Newtonsoft.Json: Input string '----------------------------425821815332553994086253' is not a valid number. Path '', line 1, position 52.

2. bodysection: binary, attach file

error message:

System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: TradematchHttpFunctions. Newtonsoft.Json: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: F. Path '', line 0, position 0.

Comment: If the body contains a csv file, you should not expect a *json* parser to understand the content.

Comment: is there another way I can debug/develop an httptrigger azure function containing a csv file?